# Parsing content of a sharepoint ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

I've got a whole bunch of .aspx files, that i need to parse some way that i can get the content of the different tags.
But not sure where to start, any pointers on some methods in c# i could take a look at?

Here is one of the files, so you can see the structure:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingPageImage,PublishingPageContent,SummaryLinks,SummaryLinks2,Send_x0020_as_x0020_newsletter,IsSent,ArticleStartDate,PublishingDateTime"><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">38</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:IsSent msdt:dt="string">1</mso:IsSent>
<mso:PublishingDateTime msdt:dt="string">2012-06-20T14:05:00Z</mso:PublishingDateTime>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">Poul  Damgård</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
<mso:Send_x0020_as_x0020_newsletter msdt:dt="string">1</mso:Send_x0020_as_x0020_newsletter>
<mso:StartDate msdt:dt="string">2012-06-20T14:00:00Z</mso:StartDate>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D40075C4234BBFE1134882EF09B2917977B5</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:PublishingContactName msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactName>
<mso:Comments msdt:dt="string">Der skal slagtes 30 procent flere økologiske svin på Danish Crown i Herning. Det giver ikke flere arbejdspladser, men er med til at sikre beskæftigelsen.
</mso:Comments>
<mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">http://www.nnf.dk/_catalogs/masterpage/NNF_underside_nyhed_bred_pl.aspx, NNF Nyheds side, bred</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
<mso:TaskStatus msdt:dt="string">Not Started</mso:TaskStatus>
<mso:SystemTask msdt:dt="string">0</mso:SystemTask>
<mso:PublishingPageImage msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingPageImage>
<mso:PublishingPageContent msdt:dt="string">&lt;p&gt;​&lt;strong&gt;Der skal slagtes 30 procent flere økologiske svin på Danish Crown i Herning. Det giver ikke flere arbejdspladser, men er med til at sikre beskæftigelsen.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;em&gt;Af Claus Gjedsig&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;– Kom bare med flere økologiske grise. Vi skal nok få dem slagtet. Og bliver vi presset, sendes de traditionelle grise til andre af Danish Crowns slagterier, siger fabrikschef Kaj Meldgaard, Danish Crown i Herning.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;Når man forventer flere slagtninger af økogrise i Herning skyldes det, at fødevareminister Mette Gjerskov har meldt ud, at støtten til investeringer i økologisk jordbrug skal hæves. Hun forventer at komme med 80 millioner støttekroner frem til 2020.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;Det er en nyhed, der skaber glæde hos den daglige leder af slagteriet Friland, Randi Kok. Hidtil har det nemlig knebet med at få danske økogrise nok til slagtning, fordi landmændene ikke har kunnet få finansieret en omlægning til økologisk produktion.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Opkøber svenske svin&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Frilands økosvin slagtes udelukkende på Danish Crown i Herning.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;– Efterspørgslen på økologisk svinekød er stor. Derfor må Friland lige nu opkøbe svenske svin for at følge med efterspørgslen fra udlandet. De danske forbrugere får kun dansk produceret økokød, siger Randi Kok.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;Friland slagter i år omkring 100.000 danske økosvin. Randi Kok forventer, at de til næste år vil slagte op mod 130.000 danske økosvin.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Fastholder job&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Fabrikschef Kaj Meldgaard siger, at slagtning af flere økosvin ikke betyder det helt store for beskæftigelsen.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;– Der er ikke planer om at ansætte flere medarbejdere. Omvendt betyder det, at vi kan sikre beskæftigelsen. Og økogrisene kommer jo ikke fra dag til dag, siger han.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;Den udmelding er afdelingsformand Steen Hartmann, Fødevareforbundet NNF Midtvestjylland, meget glad for.&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;– Vi har de senere år mistet over 3000 arbejdspladser i det midt- og vestjyske område. Derfor er det positivt, at beskæftigelsen sikres på Danish Crown i Herning. Hellere stilstand end tilbagegang, siger han.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
</mso:PublishingPageContent>
<mso:Kategorier msdt:dt="string">20;#Global;#1;#Nyheder</mso:Kategorier>
<mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt="string">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
<title>Økogrise sikrer job</title></head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you consider looking at the HTML Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It may not have everything you need but I believe it has plenty to get you heading in the direction you are looking to go.

Hope that helps.